# Node.js SSL Certificate Error

Tags: ssl-certificate, node.js

I'm trying to use my purchased SSL certificate in Node.js - this certificate works perfectly in Nginx and Apache without any errors.

However, when I try to use it in Node.js, I get this error :

```
tls.js:1124
throw new Error('Missing PFX or certificate + private key.');
      ^
Error: Missing PFX or certificate + private key.
at Server (tls.js:1124:11)
at new Server (https.js:35:14)
at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:54:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/home/server.js:9:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Here is my server.js code :

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello Http\r\n');
});
server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

I noticed some examples require converting the .crt and .key to .pem format. I am able to convert the .crt file, but converting the .key file gives me this error:

```
[localhost ~]$ openssl x509 -in key.key -out key.pem -outform PEM
unable to load certificate
34379118248:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I am at loss on what to do next. As I mentioned earlier, this SSL certificate is currently installed and running on Nginx and Apache without any issues.

Any ideas what I can try next?

** SOLVED **

I just needed change the 'createServer' line to :

```
var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A private key is in RSA format, not X509. Use "rsa" instead of "x509" in your openssl conversion command.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to convert the cert and key to .pem, but node is still throwing the error : Error: Missing PFX or certificate + private key.

Comment: Solved - added solution to original question.

Comment: by "rsa" do you mean genrsa?